# JSP, Call servlet in page load

Tags: jsp, servlets, pageload

I' new to java programming. I used to do `.NET`. In my new project which is using java, I want to read the database and load some data into the `texboxes` in my `jsp` page.

I used to do this using `pageload` method in `.NET` development. I can't find a propper way to do this in `jsp`.

For now I used the below code samples and it did not work as I wanted.

in servelet

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        //processRequest(request, response);

        request.setAttribute("username", "Uditha");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Download.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

In JSP

```
<jsp:include page="/PageLoad" />

<a id="btnUserAccount" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">${result}</a>
```

It would be very helpful is someone can help me do this. Thank you.

Comment: So, what URL is displayed in your address bar, what do you expect to happen (and why), and what happens instead? Which URL is the servlet mapped to?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Downloader/Downloader.jsp
with a blank page.

Comment: And what does this Downloader.jsp contain? How about the answers to the other questions?

Comment: Anyway, you need to learn about MVC. It's quite simple: you go to a URL. This URL is not the URL of a JSP. It's the URL of a servlet, which is the controller. The servlet gets data from the database (the model), stores them in request attributes, and forward to a JSP (the view). The JSP then simply generates HTML displaying the attributes stored by the servlet. As simple as that.